# Visual Studio 2019 Azure App not getting published

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, azure-deployment

I'm facing issues in deploying my ASP.NET MVC in Azure from VS 2019. While publishing from local repository, I don't see any form coming up for filling the details about the project. Instead prompts me to login again.

Creating the Azure App service and creating the profile button next

[image]

I've already logged in but there is no information to the publishing platform specified.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While publishing from local repository, I don't see any form coming up for filling the details about the project. Instead prompts me to login again.

If you do not have any **Azure subscriptions**, you can not create App Service and publish your project to Azure.

In Visual Studio Server Explorer (as below) or Azure portal, you can find information about your subscriptions.

[image]

Besides, if you'd like to add subscription for your billing account , you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/create-subscription#create-a-subscription-in-the-azure-portal

Comment: Could you please double check on Azure Subscription as for publishing the Azure App Services there is pre-requisites Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2019#prerequisites